# Print all characters upto a matching pattern from a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Maybe a silly question but I have a text file that needs to display everything upto the first pattern match which is a '/'. (all lines contain no blank spaces)

**Example.txt:**

```
somename/for/example/
something/as/another/example
thisfile/dir/dir/example
```

**Preferred output:**

```
somename
something
thisfile
```

I know this grep code will display everything after a matching pattern:

```
grep -o '/[^\n]*' '/my/file.txt'
```

So is there any way to do the complete opposite, maybe rm everything after matching pattern or invert to display my preferred output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling an external command like `grep`, you can get the same results your require with the `sed` command, i.e.

```
 echo "something/as/another/example" | sed 's:/.*::'
 something
```

Instead of focusing on what  you want to keep, think about what you want to remove, in this case everything after the first '/' char. This is what this `sed` command does.

The leading `s` means substitute, the `:/.*:` is the pattern to match, with `/.*` meaning match the first `/' char and all characters after that. The 2nd half of the`sed`command is the replacement. With`::`, this means replace with nothing.

The traditional idom for sed is to use `s/str/rep/`, using `/` chars to delimit the search from the replacement, but you can use any character you want after the initial `s` (substitute) command.

Some seds expect the `/` char, and want a special indication that the following character is the sub/replace delimiter. So if `s:/.*::` doesn't work, then `s\:/.*::` should work.

IHTH.

Comment: Wow I just tried your code which was something i was looking for, then I did a noob modification to it (sed 's:/.*::' /my/text.txt) and it worked smack bang as I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yu can use a much simpler reg exp:

`/[^/]*/`

The forward slash after the carat is what you're matching to.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2szu4jLL/)**

Comment: Didn't quite work for me but Im keeping that in mind for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming filename as "file.txt"

```
cat file.txt | cut -d "/" -f 1
```

Here, we are cutting the input line with "/" as the delimiter (-d "/"). Then we select the first field (-f 1).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include starting anchor `^` and also the `/` in a negated character class.

```
grep -o '^[^/]*' file
```